# Location of website images and text in joomla 1.5 package

Tags: image, text, joomla, directory

A joomla 1.5 website was hacked and i was commissioned to rebuild it from scratch as the current build was unusable.

the hosting company "cleaned" it and rendered it unusable.

I personally never used joomla and i just downloaded the Joomla files and folders hoping i could find the original text and images used when the website was still up and running.

No such luck.

Does anyone know where the client uploaded images and text is in a joomla 1.5 folder tree?

Thanks in advance.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is stored in the database in #__content. Each article will be in a new row. The user uploaded images are stored in the images subfolder of the joomla installation. However remember some may be stored within a component or modules sub-folders if installed with them.